# Convert Map[String,AnyRef] to seq of anorm.NamedParameter

Tags: java, scala, anorm

I have Java lib for SQL query builder.

Builder returns:

`String` ->  sql query with param placeholders

`Map<String,Object>` -> map of named parameters.

When I use the builder in `SCALA`, I get `util.Map[String,AnyRef]` which I cannot convert to `Seq[NamedParameters]` and use like: `SQL(queryString).on(PARAMETERS)`.

maybe someone has suggestion how implement any convertors to NamedParameters?

First idea was to create maper by type:

```
  implicit def buildParamVal(a: Any): ParameterValue = {
    a match {
     case v: Boolean => ParameterValue.toParameterValue(v)
     case v: Int => ParameterValue.toParameterValue(v) ...}
```

But it doesn;t look like good solution, problems appear with `null` and `collections.`

Comment: `Any` or `AnyRef` types are not supported, as not allowing to resolve type mappings

Comment: Ow, thank you, I noticed that these types are not supported.I am asking for solution in this case,

Comment: There is no solution in this case, as this case means value types is unknown. Generally speaking in Scala using `Any` or `AnyRef` means there is something wrong.